# Error while installing tabpy module with dependencies on an offline environment: "No matching distribution found for wheel"

Tags: python, linux, setuptools, tabpy

I'm trying to install tabpy module for `Tableau` usage. The server that i'm using is and offline server (no internet access). I downloaded the package and all dependencies and transferred to the server. When i run the install command below and while the dependencies are installing i'm getting an error from setuptools installation.
`Python version is 3.9.12` and tabpy version that I am trying to install is 2.9.0. There is already a `setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl` package in my folder.

```
(venv) (base) [user@server tabpy]$ pip install tabpy-2.9.0.tar.gz --use-pep517 -f ./ --no-index
Looking in links: ./
Processing ./tabpy-2.9.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      Looking in links: ./
      Processing ./setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried older versions of setuptools by changing the wheel file with older ones such as 67.8.0 and 52.0.0. Nothings changed.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, i replaced the ss with text.